# When nobody's on the counter in a shop, how do I say?

Tags: questions, conversation

Would it be okay to say like below to a clerk near the counter?

> I would like to check out

And if a cashier is on the counter but is doing something else, can I ask shortly like below?

> Are you open?

Thank you!

Comment: Your two examples do not mean the same. Did you intend that?

Comment: A cashier is at a counter, but can be "on the (cash) register". That means: doing the job of cashier. "Are you on the register?" "Are you open" is OK because when  a cashier leaves their post, they close the register.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is perfectly acceptable. If you want to make it more polite, add a greeting before it such as "Hello."

The second one largely depends on if the shop has multiple counters and cash registers in place for checkout. Asking this question would mean asking if this particular counter is open for checkout. If there is only one counter in the store it could be seen as rhetorical and taken the wrong way, such like

> Are you open? If so, are you planning on doing your job?

If there is someone at the counter and they do not notice you are there, you can get their attention politely by saying "Excuse me."

Answer (score 0):

"Check out" sounds like the term used when leaving hotel. I'd just use

> Excuse me. I'd like to buy this.

For the second one, I'd probably just say

> Excuse me (and smile)

or

> Hello (and look expectant)

But "Excuse me. Are you open?" is correct English and reasonably natural.

Comment: "Check out" meaning "pay for purchases and leave" is common usage in American English in the context of grocery stores and such. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/checkout